# Using "labbook" document class with Lualatex

Tags: luatex, unicode, labbook

I want to use the `labbook` document class, but it seems not to work with LuaLaTeX compiler, with some UTF-8 error (hereafter). Is there any possibility to make it work ?

```
String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence. \def\fk@@getatdashsep@list#1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file is unfortunately written in latin-1, however only a few lines are affected, if I load `labbook.cls` into my editor and save a copy of it in UTf8 it loads into luatex with no errors and the following lines have changed

```
9c9
< %% Copyright (C) 2002 Frank Küster.
---
> %% Copyright (C) 2002 Frank KÃ¼ster.
128c128
< \def\fk@@getatdashsep@list#1§{%
---
> \def\fk@@getatdashsep@list#1Â§{%
194c194
<     \protected@edef\fk@exp@indexlist{#1§\fk@exp@indexlist}
---
>     \protected@edef\fk@exp@indexlist{#1Â§\fk@exp@indexlist}
196c196
<     \protected@edef\fk@subexp@indexlist{#1§\fk@subexp@indexlist}
---
>     \protected@edef\fk@subexp@indexlist{#1Â§\fk@subexp@indexlist}
213c213
<       \expandafter\fk@useindexlist\fk@subexp@indexlist\relax§%
---
>       \expandafter\fk@useindexlist\fk@subexp@indexlist\relaxÂ§%
251c251
<   \expandafter\fk@useindexlist\fk@exp@indexlist\relax§%
---
>   \expandafter\fk@useindexlist\fk@exp@indexlist\relaxÂ§%
526c526
<           \expandafter\fk@useindexlist\fk@exp@indexlist\relax§%
---
>           \expandafter\fk@useindexlist\fk@exp@indexlist\relaxÂ§%
```

You should probably report that to the class author, but any editor should be able to save the file in UTF-8.

Comment: note in the display above the lines with the accented A are the UTF-8 ones (the display is confused as the diff is a mixed latin-1/utf-8 file)

Comment: Thank you for your answer @DavidCarlisle !
So you suggest to keep the version UTF-8 saved with those "Â§" ?

Comment: the@Mammouth they only look like Â§ if you view a utf8 file in a system set up for latin1 for example look at this section mark [ § ] if you select latin 1 (might be called western or other names) in your browsers view/encoding menu.

Comment: Thanks again ! A local copy of labbook.cls was messing up with my changes, works like a charm. I cannot report that issue to the author though : no email address displayed.